# Sync completely ignoring Restrictions to do approved products

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex, hybris-data-hub

I am **trying to sync only approved Products**, unfortunately below created Restrictions completely ignored by sync.

```
INSERT_UPDATE CatalogVersionSyncJob;code[unique=true];sourceVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true];targetVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true];syncPrincipals(uid);sessionUser(uid)
 ;testSyncJob;Default:Staged;Default:Online;syncUserGroup;syncUser



 INSERT_UPDATE JobSearchRestriction; code[unique = true] ; job(code) ; query ; type(code)
; syncuser_restriction ; mySyncJob ; {approvalStatus} IN ({{ SELECT {pk} FROM {ArticleApprovalStatus} WHERE {code}= 'approved'}}) ; Product


INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction;code[unique=true];name[lang=en];query;principal(UID);restrictedType(code);active;generate
;syncuser_restriction;Sync Only Approved Products;{approvalStatus} IN ({{ SELECT {pk} FROM {ArticleApprovalStatus} WHERE {code}= 'approved'}});syncUserGroup;Product;true;true
```

**May I know the reason of ignoring above restrictions by sync? and how to fix?**

Comment: anyone aware of above issue?

Comment: I will be glad if anyone could be able to answer above issue...

Comment: no one knows on above issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use `approvalStatus`.

See [this post](https://www.sap.com/cxworks/article/2589632280/catalog_synchronization#CatalogSynchronization-WhichItemsWillbeSynchronized?) from SAP

You can find below a copy-paste

> Which Items Will be Synchronized?
>
> Synchronizing can be done either on the entire catalog version
> (easiest option) or can be done on a select group of items.
>
> There are two typical use cases for filtering the items to be
> synchronized:
>
> There is a requirement to synchronize only approved products. The recommended practice is to avoid using the out of the box
> "approvalStatus" attribute as you may want to synchronize products
> which are not approved. The recommended practice is to introduce a new
> attribute "readyForSync" as a boolean type. A business user or a
> business logic would be responsible for setting the attribute to TRUE.
> A restriction would guarantee that only confirmed products are
> synchronized.
> Synchronize a subset of items (such as products of a specific category) to a specified target catalog version.
>
> One important consideration, in an enterprise setting where there are
> many concurrent product managers, is the coordination of the
> synchronization. The "readyForSync" flag can be helpful to schedule
> products for the next synchronization run. However, it offers limited
> granularity of control in an environment where there are multiple
> teams managing their own lines of products. To provide a more granular
> coordination, it is recommended to use a hybrid approach where the
> "readyForSync" flag and the category-specific synchronization are used
> together. This way, different teams managing different brands or
> categories would not affect each other in unintended ways and it
> offers more flexibility in terms of when the synchronization can be
> run.
>
> If you synchronize using a scheduled cron job then a search
> restriction can be used with a dedicated synchronization user:
>
> `INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction|code[unique=true]|name[lang=en]|query|principal(UID)|restrictedType(code)|active|generate|Backend_Sync_Product|Sync|{item.readyForSync}=1|syncgroup|Product|true|true`

---

As a side note, I don't know on which version you are working on.
It used to not work well in older version. (mentionned on [this old page](https://cxwiki.sap.com/display/hybrisALF/Catalog+Synchronization) that will probably get deleted)

> If you synchronize manually, then things can get tricky again:
>
> ```
> Concurrent invocations from more than one business users result in some of the attempts aborting without an informative error message.
> References to items in the same catalog version will not be synchronized unless marked as "copy by value" or "part-of".
> Restrictions used for scheduled cron job synchronization do not work. Everything gets synchronized.
> ```

Comment: whatever you provided answer is an alternative approach, but I have tried both the approaches and both of them are ignoring restrictions. BTW, am using 1905 version